# Mean centering with incomplete data

Tags: machine-learning, mean

In my kaggle competitions I always mean-centered (center close to zero) my input data. Once I haven't done that, my neural network doesn't converge very well.

I'm using sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing

samples = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3]).reshape(-1, 1)

scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
scaler.fit(samples)
print(scaler.transform(samples))
```

> ```
> [[-1.        ]
> [-0.33333333]
> [ 0.33333333]
> [ 1.        ]]
> ```

However, currently I'm working on a RL project where the data come from self play. That means my scaler can't fit all data from the beginning. My NN predicts QValues and learns from actual QLearning results. These QValues are quite different based on the learning episodes. i.e. 0.024, 24e-10, 24e-20, 24e-40

Is there a different approach for incomplete data?

Comment: You can use `StandardScaler`

Comment: When do I fit the standard scaler with incomplete data? I don't think it works since It has the same problem. The same Qvalue earlier to later would result differently.

Comment: There are lots of methods for incomplete data. With rest features and between missing feature,  you can validate similarity distance, median, regression-based approaches. Compare accuracy and f1 scores and choose the best approach.